# Nested Particle Systems

Tags: particles

I have a hair particle group, that takes buildings from a building group, and places them on a grid. This works perfectly fine. I recently added an emitter system to each of the buildings in the building group to show random lit windows. It shows perfectly fine in the preview when looking at the group of buildings, but when looking at the hair particle system, the buildings show as usual, but the emitter doesn't work. There are a few other buildings using the same emitter system in the scene that are not in the building group, which the emitter system is working fine.

It works fine if I convert the emitter system, but is not ideal. Is there a way to get this nested particle system to work, without converting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Particles on particles is not supported yet. I think there might be an addon somewheres for it, but you'll have to look

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise ? This worked the last time I tried it

Comment: Oh! I see what he was asking. I immediately thought of the whole hair particles on hair particles thing.

Comment: Excellent gandalf3, thank you. Leave it to the wording to allow the one relevant particle system post to evade me.